# How to change number in Mad Libs game?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a Mad Libs-style game in which there is a time limit of 1 minute. Once the time limit is reached, the game ends and "GAME OVER" is displayed. If the user finishes within the time limit, the results are displayed. I'm using a while loop and time.time() so that the first question is asked, the while loop repeats, the second question is asked, the while loop repeats, etc. But I can't figure out how to change the question number as the game progresses so that when the while loop finishes with one question, it moves on to the next.

```
start = time.time()
    questionNum = 1

    question1 = "Enter the name of a male acquaintance: "
    question2 = "Enter the name of a place: "
    question3 = "Enter an adverb: "
    question4 = "Enter a verb: "
    question5 = "Enter a plural noun: "
    question6 = "Enter a verb: "
    question7 = "Enter the vocation of a person: "
    question8 = "Enter a verb ending with -ing: "
    question9 = "Enter an emotion (past tense): "
    question10 = "Enter a grade letter: "
    question11 = "Enter a school subject: "
    question12 = "Enter the meaning of the letter grade A: "
    question13 = "Enter the meaning of the letter grade B: "
    question14 = "Enter the meaning of the letter grade C: "
    question15 = "Enter the meaning of the letter grade D: "
    question16 = "Enter the meaning of the letter grade E: "
    question17 = "Enter the meaning of the letter grade F: "
    question18 = "Enter an aggressive verb: "

    while time.time() - start < 60:
        answer1 = input(question1)
        questionNum +=1
    else:
        print("Too bad, slowpoke. GAME OVER!")
```

Comment: Use a list of questions rather than individual variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have them in a list of some sort:

```
questions = [ "Enter the name of a male acquaintance: ",
  "Enter the name of a place: ",
  ... ]
```

then you'll collect answers in a list too:

```
answers = []
while time.time() - start < 60:
    answers.append(input(questions[questionNum]))
    questionNum +=1
```

You can then check if user have answered all the questions by comparing lengths of question and answer lists:

```
if len(answers) < len(questions):
    print("Too bad, slowpoke. GAME OVER!")
```